# How to change I/O scheduler for a disk in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-16.04, scheduler

I am trying to set noop I/O scheduler for my disk. However, I am getting this error,

```
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I checked and found that there is no I/O scheduler option in my disk.

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[none]
```

Is there any way to set noop I/O scheduler for above disk ?

Comment: Is this a virtual machine?  VMs include virtual I/O devices so the actual I/O device scheduling is performed by the hypervisor kernel.

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL yes, its in google cloud. Can I do something from myside ?

Comment: I am not familiar with what type disk/storage setup google compute has. Maybe you can consult the docs there. It also depends on what are you trying to achieve. Are you seeing I/O issues? Then what is the nature of that issue. Why noop?

Comment: Replacing none with noop seems useless to me. I guess you don't have access to the physical device anyway so there is nothing to set.

Comment: I am also interested in this. I use MS Azure Cloud and I observed 2 cases: Ubuntu 14.04 VM provides 3 schedulers while Ubuntu16.04 VM does not provide any. It is interesting why this is the case.